# Continuous semimartingale and limit

Tags: probability, martingales

Let $X_t=X_0+M_t+A_t$ a continuous semi-martingale.
Let $g: \Bbb R \to [-1,1]$, of class $C^{\infty}$, with $g(x)= \left\{ \begin{matrix} -1, & x \le 0 \\ 1, & x \ge 1 \end{matrix} \right.$. Let $f_n : \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ with $f_n(0)=0$ and $f_n'(x)=g(nx) \ \forall x \in \Bbb R$.

Show $\lim \limits _{n \to \infty} \sup \limits _{t \ge 0} | \int \limits _0 ^t [\text{sgn} (X_s) - f_n' (X_s)] \Bbb d M_s| = 0$ in $L^2(\Omega,P)$ and $\lim \limits _{n \to \infty} \sup \limits _{t \ge 0} |\int \limits _0 ^t [\text{sgn} (X_s) - f_n' (X_s)] \Bbb d A_s| = 0$, where $\text{sgn} (x) = \left\{ \begin{matrix} 1, & x \ge 0 \\ -1, & x<0 \end{matrix} \right.$.

How to do these two questions? Thank you.

Comment: What are your thoughts?

Comment: I don't have idea

Comment: I'm sure you have *some* idea if you're able to type out the question. What are you having trouble with? Not understanding the definitions? Unclear as to what you need to show? You understand what the question is asking, but you don't know how to approach it? If you explain what you have difficulty with, then someone here can help you understand.

Comment: to begin with if $x \notin ]0,1[,|sgn(x)-f_n'(x)|=0$. $X_s> 1$ ,$limsup|\int_0^t[sgn(X_s)-f_n'(X_s)]dM_s|=0$ but if $X_s \leq 1$, I don't know